# adb device always unauthorized

Tags: adb, linux

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04

```
adb version
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.32
```

However, when I plug in my devices for testing via ADB, I always get an unauthorized error.

```
adb devices

List of devices attached 
LGD855a1098057  unauthorized
```

adb works flawlessly on Windows 7 x64 SP1 with Koushik Douttas Universal ADB driver and my friend's Macbook, this singles out the Ubuntu 16.04 as the problem.

Things I have tried:

- I tried revoking previous USB authorizations: nothing happened.
- Switching adb debugging on and off: however, the CLI just keeps telling me with the unauthorized error.
- Switching ports: each port on my 16-port development rig has been tried.
- Updating adb:

  ```
  android-tools-adb is already the newest version (5.1.1r36+git20160322-0ubuntu3).
  android-tools-fastboot is already the newest version (5.1.1r36+git20160322-0ubuntu3).
  ```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Same problem here with exact same Linux Ubuntu version. The solution for me that works well is

1. `adb kill-server`
2. `sudo adb usb`

After this, your mobile will ask for authorization and work well. So, adb needs root privilege.

Comment: This is the reliable way to do it. The other answers may work fir a while, but this one keeps going.

Answer (score 1):

Kill the *adb* server if running:

```
adb kill-server
```

Remove `~/.android` directory with all its content:

```
rm -rf ~/.android
```

Don't forget to *Revoke USB debugging authorizations* in developer options on your Android device.

Start the adb server:

```
adb start-server
```

Search for devices:

```
adb devices
```

Comment: `rm -rf ~/.android` fixed a similar kind of issue for me. thanks

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

- I revoked previous USB authorizations
- I killed and restarted the adb server using these commands:

  ```
  adb kill-server
  adb start-server
  ```
- I restarted the phone
- And ran `adb devices`

And the device didn't appear as unauthorized!