# How can I transfer android data to PC (windows) given that phone screen is not working and I don't want to replace it.?

Tags: broken-screen, accessibility

I have a LeTV android phone launched in India in 2016, now the company has been shut down. Few days back, my mobile screen suddenly just went off. Now it is just switched ON. Before dismantling it, I want to transfer my data to my PC as I haven't set backup on. I tried through command prompt adb commands but it is saying  device in unauthorized, do it by clicking on screen which I can't do. Please help me, how can I transfer data.

Comment: Both of your queries are of most widely discussed topics. Make a search and you will get hundreds of answers like [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/36065/218526) and [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/150120/218526).

Comment: First buy USB-OTG adapter and try to connect keyboard/mouse. If no USB-OTG support, you could flash rom with ro.adb.secure=0 and userdebug. or inject init.d script which will sync /data/misc/adb/adb_keys from any given location (cache, system, sdcard). For unencrypted Mediatek devices simply readback with SP Flash Tool

Comment: TWRP has adb shell, too https://twrp.me/faq/openrecoveryscript.html

Answer (score 0):

ADB commands won't work if you haven't set up USB debugging prevoiusly, and also allowed your computer to debug the phone.

If I understand you correctly that your phone only turns on, but you cannot see anything on the screen, I am afraid nothing can be done. Take your phone to a person who can fit in another display. Otherwise, this seems virtually impossible.

Comment: OP stated that usb-debugging is on, just not able to confirm the RSA-Key